# SQL substring get all digits before certain character

Tags: sql, postgresql

The result in a Column is:

```
14800:DATAB Unload
```

I'm trying to get all the digits before the : so i receive only the number.

What should i put in my select to get this done?

Comment: mysql  or postgresql ????

Comment: postgresql is it im using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression for that:

```
select regexp_replace(the_column, '(^[0-9]+):.*', '\1')
from the_table;
```

Or use the `left()`  function:

```
select left(the_column, strpos(col, ':') - 1)
from the_table;
```

The regex is more robust against strings that do not contain a number or a `:`. If you are certain that **every** value will have a `:` in it, the second solution should be preferred as it is much faster.

The following example:

```
with data (col) as (
  values ('14800:DATAB Unload'), ('Another Unload')
)
select regexp_replace(col, '(^[0-9]+):.*', '\1'), 
       left(col, strpos(col, ':') - 1)
from data;
```

returns:

```
regexp_replace  | left       
----------------+------------
14800           | 14800      
Another Unload  | Another Unloa
```

The second value will be left unchanged by the regex solution, but will cut off the last character when using `left()`.

Answer (score 1):

for  mysql

```
SELECT LEFT(you_column,LOCATE(':',your_column) - 1) from your_table
```

for postgresql

```
SELECT substr(you_column , 1,  position( ':' in  your_column) - 1) from your_table
```

or

```
SELECT left(you_column , position( ':' in  your_column) - 1) from your_table
```

Comment: I am using postgresql, and im getting an error at : <pre>position(':',your_column)</pre>

Comment: @scaisEdge PostgreSQL also supports `left` function.

Comment: @Abelisto   . thanks  .. answer update .. (the substr i for a more generic approach) ..